# Why does `join` un-capitalize strings in an array?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a method that capitalizes each word in a string. Without using the `join` method, I can obtain a correct array (eg. `david copperfield` == `["David", "Copperfield"]`):

```
def titleize(words)
  single_words = words.split(/ /)
  single_words.map {|i| i.capitalize}
  single_words.join(" ")
end
```

When I `join` the elements, they revert back to lowercase. I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use **map!** instead of **map**, because **map** returns new array, not changes initial.

```
def titleize(words)
    single_words = words.split(/ /)
    single_words.map! {|i| i.capitalize}
    single_words.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the destructive version of `map`: `map!`:

```
single_words.map! { |i| i.capitalize}
```

Answer (score 2):

`join` does not un-capitalize it. You threw out the result of capitalizing, and passed the original uncapitalized array to `join`.

If your intent is to capitalize each substring separated by `/ /`, then the more normal and better way is:

```
def titleize(words)
  words.gsub(/[^ ]+/, &:capitalize)
end
```

I am not quite sure why you are using an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) documentation page, you'll find out that it

> Invokes the given block once for each element of self.
>
> Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

So `.map` returns new array, but doesn't modify the one you provide. That's why your method has been working, when `.map` was the last instruction.

To fix your code, you could either replace `.map` by `.map!`, that modifies provided array(`single_words`):

```
def titleize(words)
  single_words = words.split(/ /)
  single_words.map! {|i| i.capitalize}
  single_words.join(" ")
end
```

or replace `.capitalize` with `.capitalize!`, which modifies strings:

```
def titleize(words)
  single_words = words.split(/ /)
  single_words.map {|i| i.capitalize!}
  single_words.join(" ")
end
```

or perform `.join` right after `.map`:

```
def titleize(words)
  single_words = words.split(/ /)
  single_words.map {|i| i.capitalize}.join(' ')
end
```

in fact, your method is simple enough to be one-liner:

```
def titleize(string)
  string.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end
```